# Beamer: centering only figure in column

Tags: floats, columns, alignment

I have a simple question in beamer: I have a slide with two columns, where each column contains some figures and some text. I want the figures to be centered within the columns but the text should be aligned to the left.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel} 


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
    \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
    some short text
    \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item first item
    \item second item
    \item third item
    \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
    for $x<y$:
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    
    ... but for $x>y$:
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-c}
    \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

As you can see I used the figures environment in the left column. This does center the image, as I want, but also adds some vertical whitespace above and below the image. Now in the right column I want the images to be centered, but without this additional whitespace. I have also tried the center environment, which also adds whitespace.

Comment: There is also `\hfil\includegraphics{...}\newline` or `\par`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: The trick is simply  `{\centering <you image> \par}`.

Long answer: The trick is simply  `{\centering <you image> \par}`. The `\par` could be changed by a blank line, but note that `{\centering <you image>}\par` will not work (compare in the MWE).

On the other hand, if there are not captions, instead of figure you can use a center environment to center and add some vertical space.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
    \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
    \dotfill\par% to see column width
    some short text
    \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=.1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{center}
    some short text
    \dotfill\par% to see column width

    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
    \dotfill\par% to see column width
    for $x<y$:\par
    {\centering\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{example-image-b}\par}
    ... but for $x>y$:\par
     {\centering\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{example-image-c}}\par %oooppp!!

    \dotfill\par% to see column width
    \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is a bit confusing but maybe this is what you are looking for --the `figure` environ will center the image and the `[T]` option in `columns` will give the top alignment of the shorter column with respect to the longer column

[image]

```
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel} 


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
    \begin{columns}[T]
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
    some short text
    \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item first item
    \item second item
    \item third item
    \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
    for $x<y$:\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \end{figure}
    ... but for $x>y$:\begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-c}
    \end{figure}
    \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**edit--to remove whitespace**

with the help of`\vspace` you can adjust to your liking

```
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
    some short text\vspace{-6pt}
    \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{figure}\vspace{-12pt}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, but the problem is not vertical alignment. I only want the images horizontally centered. Your suggestion using the figures environment does this, but also adds some whitespace above and below the image, which I don't want in the right column.